# Parent with position absolute doesn't wrap child elements

Tags: html, css, position

I have a parent element with position absolute and child elements which are displayed outside parent and behind elements that come after parent.

`div.content` only has its padding's width and height, `div.text` is displayed below, outside of it.

```css
.container {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.content {
   padding: 40px 32px 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
}

.text {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   overflow: hidden;
   line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="text"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if you remove position relative does it work?

Comment: no, it doesn't...